# Twitter Embedded Tweets aren't visible if HTML divs are in certain order

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I'm building a web application using Vite.js + HTML/CSS/JS and jQuery. I want to embed tweets on a page using lists of twitter post id's returned from an API. I am using [Twitter's Javascript Embed Tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-javascript-factory-function) factory function to achieve this and encountering a strange problem. Everything works when the HTML divs are in a certain order, but if I try to move things around, one of the list of tweets doesn't display properly.

To explain further: I have two HTML divs that I'm using as containers for the tweets -- the first container displays tweets from a list of "positive" posts, and the second container displays tweets from a list of "negative" posts (the API returns these lists). When the page loads, the tweets are populated, but remain hidden. The user must click a button "display negative tweets" or "display positive tweets" in order toggle them to hidden/visible.

Now, if I arrange the HTML divs as follows, everything works properly:

```
Negative Tweets Container
Positive Tweets Container
```

However, if I reverse the order of the containers, the negative tweets stop displaying on button click:

```
Positive Tweets Container
Negative Tweets Container
```

It's quite strange, you'd think that *whichever div* was placed on the bottom would have the same issue, but it's only the `negative tweets container` that stops working properly when placed on the bottom. The code I'm using to populate and display the tweets for each section is identical except for the html id tags and variable names, so it doesn't make sense to me that the order of HTML divs would cause an issue. I've logged everything in the console, there are no errors and no indication of what is causing the problem.

I recreated the issue in two codepens for convenience:

[Negative Div on Top](https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/OJQKMMo) (everything works)
[Negative Div on Bottom](https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/gOvVweZ) (negative tweets won't show)

Please note, the two codepen projects are identical except for the order of HTML divs, so you can just look at one if you want, all you have to do is try putting the negative tweets container below the positive tweets container, or vice versa, and you will see the issue.

Here are code snippets as well. This is the working version, if you switch the order of tweet containers, the negative tweets will stop displaying properly:

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////
// On page load, populate tweets, but they will remain
// hidden until user clicks "display" button
//////////////////////////////////////////
$(function() {
  populatePositiveTweets();
  populateNegativeTweets();
});

//////////////////////////////////////////
// test data -- positive
//////////////////////////////////////////
const positiveData = {
  brand: "serena",
  logo: "nike",
  match_count: 5,
  post_id_list: [{
      post_id: "1400014236013764615"
    },
    {
      post_id: "1399610411557683201"
    },
    {
      post_id: "1399594614093271041"
    },
    {
      post_id: "1399566283469819907"
    },
    {
      post_id: "1399538218060500997"
    }
  ],
  return_error: null
};

//////////////////////////////////////////
// test data -- negative
//////////////////////////////////////////
const negativeData = {
  brand: "serena",
  logo: "nike",
  match_count: 5,
  post_id_list: [{
      post_id: "1400014236013764615"
    },
    {
      post_id: "1399610411557683201"
    },
    {
      post_id: "1399594614093271041"
    },
    {
      post_id: "1399566283469819907"
    },
    {
      post_id: "1399538218060500997"
    }
  ],
  return_error: null
};

//////////////////////////////////////////
// function to populate positive tweets
//////////////////////////////////////////
const populatePositiveTweets = () => {
  // Store the list of post id's in variable
  const positiveTweetsList = positiveData.post_id_list;
  console.log(positiveTweetsList);

  // set up the variables
  var subs;
  var tempString;
  var col1 = "",
    col2 = "",
    col3 = "";
  var column_index = 1;

  // loop through the results to build the three column strings
  for (subs = 0; subs < positiveTweetsList.length; subs++) {
    if (column_index == 1) {
      col1 += "<div class='embed-responsive' id='tweetArea" + subs + "'></div>";
    } else if (column_index == 2) {
      col2 += "<div class='embed-responsive' id='tweetArea" + subs + "'></div>";
    } else if (column_index == 3) {
      col3 += "<div class='embed-responsive' id='tweetArea" + subs + "'></div>";
    }
    column_index += 1;
    if (column_index == 4) {
      column_index = 1;
    }
  }

  // write out the column html code
  document.getElementById("tweetCol1__positive").innerHTML = col1;
  document.getElementById("tweetCol2__positive").innerHTML = col2;
  document.getElementById("tweetCol3__positive").innerHTML = col3;

  // loop through the results to display the tweets
  for (subs = 0; subs < positiveTweetsList.length; subs++) {
    // get the post id
    post_id = positiveTweetsList[subs];

    // build the twitter area name
    twitter_area = "tweetArea" + subs;

    // display the tweets
    twttr.widgets
      .createTweet(
        positiveTweetsList[subs].post_id,
        document.getElementById(twitter_area), {}
      )
      .then(function(e1) {
        window.setTimeout(hideOverlay, 5000);
      })
      .catch(function(e2) {});
  }
};

//////////////////////////////////////////
// function to populate negative tweets
///////////////////////////////////////////
const populateNegativeTweets = () => {
  // Store the list of post id's in variable
  const negativeTweetsList = negativeData.post_id_list;


  // set up the variables
  var subs;
  var tempString;
  var col1 = "",
    col2 = "",
    col3 = "";
  var column_index = 1;

  // loop through the results to build the three column strings
  for (subs = 0; subs < negativeTweetsList.length; subs++) {
    if (column_index == 1) {
      col1 += "<div class='embed-responsive' id='tweetArea" + subs + "'></div>";
    } else if (column_index == 2) {
      col2 += "<div class='embed-responsive' id='tweetArea" + subs + "'></div>";
    } else if (column_index == 3) {
      col3 += "<div class='embed-responsive' id='tweetArea" + subs + "'></div>";
    }
    column_index += 1;
    if (column_index == 4) {
      column_index = 1;
    }
  }

  // write out the column html code
  document.getElementById("tweetCol1__negative").innerHTML = col1;
  document.getElementById("tweetCol2__negative").innerHTML = col2;
  document.getElementById("tweetCol3__negative").innerHTML = col3;

  // loop through the results to display the tweets
  for (subs = 0; subs < negativeTweetsList.length; subs++) {
    // get the post id
    post_id = negativeTweetsList[subs];

    // build the twitter area name
    twitter_area = "tweetArea" + subs;

    // display the tweets
    twttr.widgets
      .createTweet(
        negativeTweetsList[subs].post_id,
        document.getElementById(twitter_area), {}
      )
      .then(function(e1) {
        window.setTimeout(hideOverlay, 5000);
      })
      .catch(function(e2) {});
  }
};

//////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to toggle tweets to show/hide
//////////////////////////////////////////
const toggleTweets = (type) => {
  let tweetsContainer = $(`#tweets-container__${type}`);

  if ($(tweetsContainer).css("display") === "none") {
    $(tweetsContainer).show();
    console.log("tweets container", $(tweetsContainer).css("display"));

  } else {
    $(tweetsContainer).hide();
    console.log("tweets container", $(tweetsContainer).css("display"));

  }
};


//////////////////////////////////////////
// Attach toggle function to buttons as click listeners
//////////////////////////////////////////
$("#tweets-btn__positive").on("click", () => {
  console.log("toggle positive tweets");
  toggleTweets("positive");
});

$("#tweets-btn__negative").on("click", () => {
  console.log("toggle negative tweets")
  toggleTweets("negative");
});
```

```css
#tweets-container__negative,
#tweets-container__positive {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
}

#no-data__negative-posts,
#no-data__positive-posts {
  display: none;
}

#parent-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery Scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- JS Add-on Scripts -->
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<div id="parent-container">

  <!-- Negative Button -->
  <button id="tweets-btn__negative">Toggle Negative Posts</button>

  <!-- Negative Tweets Container-->
  <div id="tweets-container__negative">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="negative-tweets">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="tweetCol1__negative"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="tweetCol2__negative"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="tweetCol3__negative"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--  Positive Button  -->
  <button id="tweets-btn__positive">Toggle Positive Posts</button>

  <!-- Positive Tweets Container-->
  <div id="tweets-container__positive">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="positive-tweets">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="tweetCol1__positive"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="tweetCol2__positive"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="tweetCol3__positive"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Lastly, Here's one more link to an example of the Twitter embed code that I used as a reference for my code: https://www.labnol.org/code/19933-embed-tweet-with-javascript
I know this is a complex problem, I did my best to create a minimal reproduction of the issue and provide relevant resources. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Quite simple - you have duplicated id's in your HTML - the issue is with `id='tweetArea" + subs` ... and `twitter_area = "tweetArea" + subs;` and `document.getElementById(twitter_area)` will fail to get the right element half the time

Comment: OMG - somehow I didn't think that would be a problem because of scoping but I see what you're saying. Ok. I'll implement this and confirm if it works, thank you so much.

Comment: element id's have nothing to do with "scope" - this is an example of why element id's must be unique - you could of course do `document.querySelector(\`#negative-tweets #${twitter_area}\`)....` instead of your `getElementById` - but, really, valid HTML is better

Comment: Amazing - yes I totally see what you're saying. And of course this solved the issue. Thanks again for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

As @bravo pointed out in the comments, I had duplicated id's in my HTML:

As they said,

> "the issue is with id='tweetArea" + subs ... and twitter_area =
> "tweetArea" + subs; and document.getElementById(twitter_area) will
> fail to get the right element half the time"